# How to write macros that behave like \item in an enviroment?

Tags: macros, environments

I am attempting to add an environment to a project that would take the following form:

```
\begin{example}
  \source some text goes here to be used as an example.
  \target some more text goes here as a translation for the first line.
  \expl   here goes some text that explains the translation or provides
          some comment. This part tends to be longer and may span several
          lines, but never be more than a single paragraph.
\end{example}
```

What I would like to reproduce is the behaviour of the `\item` macro in the `itemize` environment; however, I have no idea where to begin. As far as it is possible, I would prefer to have a macro that does not require brackets but takes the following lines, including single line breaks as argument delimiters.

Is writing something like:

```
\def\source#1\par{%
  \textit{#1}\par}
```

the right way to go?

Comment: What should `\source`, `\target` and `\expl` do besides doing `\item`?

Comment: Will you *always* have `\source`, then `\target` and finally `\expl`, in that order, and always used/visible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems a job for `\list` =)

```
\newenvironment{example}{
  \newcommand{\source}{\item\itshape}
  \newcommand{\target}{\item\upshape\bfseries}
  \newcommand{\expl}{\item\normalfont}
  \list{}{}}
{\endlist}
```

Then you can change the second argument of `\list` inside the definition of `example` to set up your spacing by changing the appropriate lengths (e.g. `\itemsep`).

---

If instead you wanted to know how you can make your `\source` macro swallow the following paragraph as its argument, well that's not what `\item` does as far as I can tell.
However you can do it by using some sort of delimiter as you already suggested by using `\par` in your `\def`.
In this case you need to separate each item with an empty line so that the `\par` is inserted and your macro can find the end of its parameter. This obviously would fail if you need to be able to swallow more than one paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{example}{
  \def\source##1\par{%
    \textit{##1}\par}
  \def\target##1\par{\textbf{##1}\par}
  \def\expl##1\par{##1\par}
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{example}
  \source some text goes here to be used as an example.

  \target some more text goes here as a translation for the first line.

  \expl   here goes some text that explains the translation or provides
          some comment. This part tends to be longer and may span several
          lines, but never be more than a single paragraph.

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

---

#### Update: better solution than using \par as delimiter

Using `\par` as a delimiter has a number of disadvantages.
We could avoid the extra lines etc by using `\source` `\target` and `\expl` themselves as delimiters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\example\source#1\target#2\expl#3\endexample{\textit{#1}\par\textbf{#2}\par#3\par}

\begin{document}

\example
  \source some text goes here to be used as an example.
  \target some more text goes here as a translation for the first line.
  \expl   here goes some text that explains the translation or provides
          some comment. This part tends to be longer and may span several
          lines, but never be more than a single paragraph.
\endexample

\end{document}
```

You cannot use `example` as an environment anymore but this gives you almost the same syntax and complete control on each section.
This solution requires that all the three section are always present even if empty and in that particular order. Making them optional is possible but fiddly.

---

#### A third way to get what you want

I think your ultimate goal is to have readable sourcecode.
In that case you may consider using a key-val interface.
For instance you can use the `pgfkeys` package and do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{example/.is family, example/.cd,
  source/.code = {\item \textit{#1}},
  target/.code = {\item \textbf{#1}},
  expl/.code = {\item #1}
}

\def\example#1{
  \begin{list}{}{}
    \pgfkeys{example/.cd, #1}
  \end{list}
}

\begin{document}

\example{%
  source = {some text goes here to be used as an example.},
  target = {some more text goes here as a translation for the first line.},
  expl   = {here goes some text that explains the translation or provides
            some comment. This part tends to be longer and may span several
            lines, but never be more than a single paragraph.}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Minustar I updated the answer with two other options...

Comment: I have gone with the pdfkeys solution, as as you guessed, it was a question of readability.

Comment: @Minustar in that case have a look at the pgf manual, I think in this case the most flexible solution can be achieved by using `/.store in` so you can specify the keys in any order and use styles etc...

Answer (score 2):

Can a standard `description` environment help you? The brackets can be avoided making a `newcommand`for invoking it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\startexample}{\begin{description}}
\newcommand{\stopexample}{\end{description}}
\def\source#1{\item[source:]#1}
\def\target#1{\item[target:]#1}
\def\expl#1{\item[explanation:]#1}

\begin{document}

\startexample
  \source some text goes here to be used as an example.
  \target some more text goes here as a translation for the first line.
  \expl here goes some text that explains the translation or provides
        some comment. This part tends to be longer and may span several
        lines, but never be more than a single paragraph.
\stopexample

\end{document}
```